# JdbcOperationsSessionRepository and SessionDestroyed not compatible

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session, httplistener

I am using spring boot and I am using spring session where spring creates a session in APP_SESSION table and adds rows into it. It has max_inactive_interval column which has some seconds value in it after which the session gets timed out. Now I want to do something before session times out. I wan to perform some database operation on different table and set a flag.

I have used `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` for this

```
    @Bean
@Order(1)
public JdbcOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository(
    @Qualifier("springSessionJdbcOperations") JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    JdbcOperationsSessionRepository repository = super.sessionRepository(jdbcOperations, transactionManager);
    repository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds);
    repository.setTableName(TABLE_NAME);
    return repository;
}
```

I have tried this

```
@Bean                           // bean for http session listener
public HttpSessionListener aohttpSessionListener() {
    return new HttpSessionListener() {
        @Override
        public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent session) {               // This method will be called when session created
            System.out.println("Session Created with session id+" + session.getSession().getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent session) {         // This method will be automatically called when session destroyed
            System.out.println("Session Destroyed, Session id:" + session.getSession().getId());
            // database operations
            }

        }
    };
```

But it does not work I guess according to this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1082

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean. What actually happens and what did you expect to happen? What is your test case, assuming this is a unit or Integration test?

Comment: This is not a unit or integration test. I have put a breakpoint inside sessionDestroyed() method. Session is created and destroyed as usual but my custom code inside sessionCreated() and sessionDestroyed() does not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Session JDBC does not support publishing of session events. Only Spring Session Redis supports that.

[Source code comment on line 68](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1dbaffef5e69f731c4cca335e9ba10118a23749d/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java#L66-L68)